# How to drop oldest partition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I can list the partitions with

```
SELECT
child.relname        AS child_schema
FROM pg_inherits
JOIN pg_class child         ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid ;
```

Is it guaranteed that they are listed in creation order? Because then only an additional `LIMIT 1` is required. Else this will print the oldest, the one with the lowest number in its name: (my partitions are named name_1 name_2 name_3 ...)

```
SELECT
MIN ( trim(leading 'name_' from child.relname)::int )        AS child_schema
FROM pg_inherits
JOIN pg_class child         ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid ;
```

Then I need to create a script which uses the result to execute `DROP TABLE`? Is there no easier way?

Comment: "Is it guaranteed that they are listed in creation order?" No. A SQL query with no ORDER BY clause does not guarantee the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it guaranteed that they are listed in creation order?

No.  This is likely as long as sequential scans and no dropped tables, but if you change the query and the plan changes, you could get rather unexpected results ordering-wise.  Also I would expect that once free space is re-used, the ordering may change as well.

Your current trim query is the best way.  Stick with it.